# React.js form doesn't work after pressing submit button while no errors shown

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm new to React. js., so I was trying to use the form below, but when I press the *Sign up button*, that is supposed to submit the form and show `<SignUpFormSuccess />`. There are no errors shown. Each field is filled out properly. Does anyone have any idea why the button does not submit (doesn't work)? And If I want to show the other page in case if no errors are shown, how do I do it? Would appreciate any help!

[Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/pedantic-paper-v62n5?file=/src/SignUpFormBusiness.js)

Solution provided by @antoineso works but not the way it is supposed to. The problem here is that I have 2 sign up variants. First is for a user, second for a business, as you can see variables in each are different, so when I fill out user's sign up, there is 1 field for companyName left empty. His solution work only because he added a default value to companyName, otherwise its still empty and the form cannot be submitted.

**My validateInfo.js file**

```
export default function validateInfo(values) {
    let errors = {};
    //email

    if (!values.email) {
        errors.email = 'Email required';
    } else if (!/\S+@\S+\.\S+/.test(values.email)) {
        errors.email = 'Email address is invalid';
    }

    if (!values.companyName.trim()) {
        errors.companyName = "Company Name required"
    }else if (!/^[A-Za-z]+/.test(values.companyName.trim())) {
        errors.companyName = 'Enter a valid company name';
    }

    //username
    if (!values.username.trim()) {
        errors.username = "Username required"
    }else if (!/^[A-Za-z]+/.test(values.username.trim())) {
        errors.username = 'Enter a valid username';
    }

    //fullname

    if (!values.fullname.trim()) {
        errors.fullname = 'Full Name required';
    }
    else if (!/^[A-Za-z]+/.test(values.fullname.trim())) {
        errors.fullname = 'Enter a valid Full Name';
    }



    //password

    if (!values.password) {
        errors.password = 'Password is required';
    } else if (values.password.length < 6) {
        errors.password = 'Password needs to be 6 characters or more';
    }

    return errors;
}
```

**My useForm.js file looks this way:**

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const useForm = (callback, validate) => {
  const [values, setValues] = useState({
    username: '',
    email: '',
    fullname:'',
    password: '',
    businessEmail: '',
    companyName:''
    
  });
  const [errors, setErrors] = useState({});
  const [isSubmitting, setIsSubmitting] = useState(false);

  const handleChange = e => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    setValues({
      ...values,
      [name]: value
    });
  };

  const handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    setErrors(validate(values));
    setIsSubmitting(true);
  };

  useEffect(
    () => {
      if (Object.keys(errors).length === 0 && isSubmitting) {
        callback();
      }
    },
    [callback, errors, isSubmitting]
  );

  return { handleChange, handleSubmit, values, errors };
};

export default useForm;
```

**SignUpUser.js looks this way:**

```
import React from 'react';
import useForm from '../useForm';
import validate from '../validateInfo';
import './SignUpForm.css'


const SignUpUser = ({submitForm}) => {

    const { handleChange, values, handleSubmit, errors } = useForm(submitForm,validate);

    return (

        <div className="form-content-right">
            


            <form className="form" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <h1>Join our community by setting up your account</h1>

                <div className="form-inputs">
                    <label className='form-label'>
                    </label>
                    <input
                        type="email"
                        name="email"
                        className='form-input'
                        placeholder="Email"
                        value={values.email}
                        onChange={handleChange}
                    />


                    {errors.email && <p>{errors.email}</p>}

                </div>

                <div className="form-inputs">
                    <label htmlFor="fullname" className='form-label'> </label>
                    <input
                        type="text"
                        name="fullname"
                        className='form-input'
                        placeholder="Full Name"
                        value={values.fullname}
                        onChange={handleChange}
                    />
                    {errors.fullname && <p>{errors.fullname}</p>}

                </div>

                <div className="form-inputs">
                    <label htmlFor="username" className='form-label'></label>
                    <input
                        type="text"
                        name="username"
                        className='form-input'
                        placeholder="Username"
                        value={values.username}
                        onChange={handleChange}
                    />


                    {errors.username && <p>{errors.username}</p>}
                </div>


                <div className="form-inputs">
                    <label htmlFor="password" className='form-label'> </label>
                    <input
                        type="text"
                        name="password"
                        className='form-input'
                        placeholder="Password"
                        value={values.password}
                        onChange={handleChange}
                    />

                    {errors.password && <p>{errors.password}</p>}
                </div>
                <button className="form-input-btn" type='submit'>Sign Up</button>
                <span className="form-input-login"> Already have an account?  <a href="/log-in">Login</a> </span>


            </form>


        </div>

    );
};

export default SignUpUser;
```

My SignUpFormUser.js file

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import SignUpUser from './SignUpUser';
import SignUpFormSuccess from './SignUpFormSuccess';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';


const SignUpForm = () => {
    const [isSubmitted, setIsSubmitted] = useState(false);

    function submitForm() {
        setIsSubmitted(true);
    }
    return (
        <>
            <div className="grid-container top">

                <div className="grid-item back"> 
                <Link to='/sign-up'>
                        <img src="/images/backOutline.svg" alt="" />
                    </Link>
                </div>

                <div className="grid-item logo">

                    <Link to='/' className='logo'>
                        <img src="/images/yokifyLogoBlk.svg" alt="" />
                    </Link>

                </div>

                <div className="grid-item cancel">

                    <Link to='/'>
                        <img src="/images/cancelOutline.svg" alt="" />
                    </Link>

                </div>
                </div>


                <div className='form-container'>
                    <div className="form-content-left">
                        <img src="/images/handsUp.svg" alt="people" className="form-img"/>
                    </div>

                    {!isSubmitted ? (
                        <SignUpUser submitForm={submitForm} />
                    ) : (
                            <SignUpFormSuccess />
                        )}



                
                </div>
        </>
    );
};

export default SignUpForm;
```

**SignUpBusiness**

```
import React from 'react';
import useForm from '../useForm';
import validate from '../validateInfo';
import './SignUpForm.css'

const SignUpBusiness = (submitForm) => {

    const { handleChange, values, handleSubmit, errors } = useForm(submitForm, validate);

    return (
        <div className="form-content-right">


            <form className="form" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>

                <h1>Set up your company's profile</h1>



                <div className="form-inputs">
                    <label className='form-label'> </label>
                   
                    <input
                        type="text"
                        name="companyName"
                        className='form-input'
                        placeholder="Company's Name"
                        value={values.companyName}
                        onChange={handleChange}
                    />


                    {errors.companyName && <p>{errors.companyName}</p>}

                </div>

                

                <div className="form-inputs">
                    
                    <input
                        type="text"
                        name="fullname"
                        className='form-input'
                        placeholder="Admin's Full Name"
                        value={values.fullname}
                        onChange={handleChange}
                    />
                    {errors.fullname && <p>{errors.fullname}</p>}

                </div>

                <div className="form-inputs">
                    
                    <input
                        type="text"
                        name="username"
                        className='form-input'
                        placeholder="Username"
                        value={values.username}
                        onChange={handleChange}
                    />
                    {errors.username && <p>{errors.username}</p>}
                </div>


                <div className="form-inputs">
                    {/* <label htmlFor="password" className='form-label'> </label> */}
                    <input
                        type="text"
                        name="password"
                        className='form-input'
                        placeholder="Password"
                        value={values.password}
                        onChange={handleChange}
                    />

                    {errors.password && <p>{errors.password}</p>}
                </div>
                <button className="form-input-btn" type="submit">Sign Up</button>
                <span className="form-input-login"> Already have an account?  <a href="/login">Login</a> </span>


            </form>

        </div>

    );
};

export default SignUpBusiness;
```

Comment: @HH Formatting code for readability is acceptable, removing parts of it are not. Ensure you are maintaining as close as possible the original author's code as it is perfectly reviewable.

Comment: the useEffect in your useForm don't pass the if condition because errors.length is equal to 1. Because companyName is required and you don't pass it in your form values

Comment: @antoineso companyName is passed in fact, but in another file "SignUpBusiness". Have just added this file. Please check it.

Comment: I am not sure to answer your question but I made this [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/hopeful-dust-e6jer?file=/src/SignUpUser.js)

Comment: @antoineso Thanks for your response mate, your solution works but not the way it is supposed to. The problem here is that I have 2 sign up variants. First is for the user, second for a business, as you can see variables in each are different, so when I fill out user's sign up, there is 1 field for companyName left blank. Your solution work only because you added a default value to companyName, otherwise its still empty and I cannot submit the form.

Comment: @MaksymRohovskoi Hello My Friend :) Can you create a quick sandbox for your project.. I would like to help :-) Not needed I will go through anoineso's sandbox and add your code..And see where the issue may be..Lots of file :)

Comment: @ImranRafiqRather Hi mate! So will you add your sandbox using anoineso's one or should I create mine?

Comment: If you could create your's with all the packages that will be great :)

Comment: @ImranRafiqRather Here you go man : [link] (https://codesandbox.io/s/pedantic-paper-v62n5?file=/src/SignUpFormBusiness.js)

Comment: Oh Boy!!! I was waiting and waiting but then I took a power nap !!! Which ended just now :) Are you still facing the problem Mate ! Then I will debug it after getting fresh ?

Comment: @ImranRafiqRather yep, man. Still have not figured out how to fix this one:(   Would appreciate your help!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227162/discussion-between-imran-rafiq-rather-and-maksym-rohovskoi).